# KMeans is not predicting the correct cluster

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model, data-science-model, k-means

k-means clustering is done and created 5 optimal number of clusters. (Clustering is done unevenly).
While using them in my model, the model is not choosing the exact cluster which has the exact data. This is happening to only some records.
For some records it is getting match from wrong cluster even the exact match was there in another cluster.

why this is happening ?

please give me suggestions if anyone know about this and thanks in advance...

Comment: If you have exact data about the clusters then why are you using unsupervised methods?

Answer (score 2):

Your code and explanation is lacking, but if I have to guess
Its probably because of the Normalize operation.
When using Normazlise on the test-set, the parameters of the normalization are determined by the test-set only.

You should 'fit' a normalizer on the train-set and use this fitted normalizer to transform your test-set.